# Python 2.6 Export Dictionary multi-line to Python File in dictionary format (.py file)

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I've explored other questions and I am not surprised to find there is no answer which meets my needs.

I am absorbing an existing project, and need to make some improvements on it.  A complete re-write is far in the future, and is a change in the file format is not possible at this time, thus I need a work-around.

The data source is a database, with a Key/Value Pair of fields.

I am selecting the database, and exporting.

The problem:

We are creating a new dictionary, then parsing it.

```
output = []
output.append("dictionary = {" + "\n")
# dbdata is just a dictionary of data from the database containing key and value
for result in dbdata
    output.append("\"" + str(result['key']) + "\" : \"" + str(result['value']) + "\",")
output.append("}")
response = "\n".join(output)
```

We now have a very large dictionary which will be printed out.

The output of the *current* system is this:

```
dictionary = {
    "one": "one value",
    "two": "two value",
    'three': '
    12345/54321*23:Some-Magic/Stuff
    12345/54331*23:Some-Magic/Stuff
    12345/54321*21:Some-Magic/Stuff
    12345/54321*53:Some-Magic/Stuff
    12341/54321*23:Some-Magic/Stuff
    12343/54321*23:Some-Magic/Stuff
    12347/54321*23:Some-Magic/Stuff
    12145/54321*23:Some-Magic/Stuff',
    "four":"four value", 
    'five': "['this','is','another']", 
}
```

The *desired format* would look like:

```
dictionary = {
    "one": "one value",
    "two": "two value",
    "three": """
    12345/54321*23:Some-Magic/Stuff
    12345/54331*23:Some-Magic/Stuff
    12345/54321*21:Some-Magic/Stuff
    12345/54321*53:Some-Magic/Stuff
    12341/54321*23:Some-Magic/Stuff
    12343/54321*23:Some-Magic/Stuff
    12347/54321*23:Some-Magic/Stuff
    12145/54321*23:Some-Magic/Stuff""",
    "four":"four value", 
    "five":['this','is','another'],
}
```

Note: You will see that in the existing, it is:

- Quoting key "five" when it shouldn't
- Not triple quoting "three" as it should - a multi-line value.

Notes as to why this isn't a duplicate:

- The format can't be changed to a more reasonable/sane format, i.e. CSV, JSON, YML - All other threads (very correctly) suggest changing it.
- It must maintain the multi-line format for human readability

Yes I realize its ridiculous because it's not a very human readable format.

Sorry for the long text, it's a difficult problem to explain - and I realize that this whole thing is poor design.

Thank you to anyone who can help.

Comment: It is still unclear to me what you are working with. What is `export = ["dictionary = {",(above_data_here_from_database),'}']` suppose to be? What is `above_data_here_from_database`? A tuple? Containing strings? Can you give examples?

Comment: It isn't very clear what you're asking, but could [\[Python\]: pprint.pprint](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html#pprint.pprint) help? If yes, use `pprint.pformat` to store it in a string, and then write the string to some file. Anyway, show us a sample of how it is, and how you would like it to be.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - No, There is an array being created, we are embedding the first component of a dictionary "dictionary = {", then inserting the data as key:value.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: What do you mean by "array"? Again, can you give a *concrete example* of the data you are working with? It is entirely unclear to me...

Comment: @CristiFati - I've tried prettyprint, it doesn't solve the issue. Maybe I was using it incorrectly. I will edit the post

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - My Apologies - I've edited the post to make it more clear I hope.

Answer (score 0):

I figure'd it out - at least for my own use case.

For clarity, I am performing the following:

- Check if JSON
- Check if Python list
- If String, quote it
- If multi-line, use triple quotes

Here is the code that solved my issue - of course if there are any recommendations for a better way to do it, I'd love to know.

```
import ast
import json


dictionary = {
    "one": "one value",
    "two": "two value",
    "three": """
    12345/54321*23:Some-Magic/Stuff
    12345/54331*23:Some-Magic/Stuff
    12345/54321*21:Some-Magic/Stuff
    12345/54321*53:Some-Magic/Stuff
    12341/54321*23:Some-Magic/Stuff
    12343/54321*23:Some-Magic/Stuff
    12347/54321*23:Some-Magic/Stuff
    12145/54321*23:Some-Magic/Stuff""",
    "four": "four value",
    "five": "['this','is','another']",
}


def export_python_formatting(input):
    output = "config = { \n"
    evalVal = ""

    for key, value in input.items():
        isJSON = False
        output += "    "
        key = str(key)


        # See if the value is correct JSON

        try:
            z = json.loads(value)
            # Valid JSON - This might be a possible datatype in my use case.
            output += '"' + key + '"' + ":" + "'''" + value + "'''"
            evalVal = value
            isJSON = True
        except:
            # Invalid JSON - So let's use literal_eval to see if it contains a list
            try:
                evalVal = ast.literal_eval(value)
            except SyntaxError:
                evalVal = value
            except ValueError:
                print("There was a value error with " + key)

        varType = type(evalVal)

        # print(varType)
        if varType is str:
            if "\n" in value:
                output += '"' + key + '"' + ":" + "'''" + value + "'''"
            else:
                if isJSON is False:
                    output += '"' + key + '"' + ":" + '"' + value + '"'
        else:
            output += '"' + key + '"' + ":" + str(value)

        output += ",\n"

    output  += "}"
    return output


x = export_python_formatting(dictionary)
print(x)
```

Thank you to everyone who helped out.